# Ubuntu: Problem installing Xdebug

Tags: ubuntu, installation, xdebug

I am trying to Install XDebug on Ubuntu latest version but get the following error:

```
 pecl install Xdebug
WARNING: configuration download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user
jigal@LT-Jigal:/$ sudo pecl install Xdebug
downloading xdebug-2.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.0.5.tgz (289,234 bytes)
.................done: 289,234 bytes
67 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the php5-dev package should solve your problem.
You can find this info on http://packages.ubuntu.com/, with phpize5 (linked automatically to phpize)